# Wasn't able to export the data to Excel in AX2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

When i tried to export data to excel I'm getting an error

> **You don't have permission to save in the Excel export location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission**

after I close the Alter message I'm getting another error in the infolog like

> **The directory name is invalid**

I tried open export location in **File --> Tools --> Options --> General --> Miscellaneous --> Open Export Location** When i clicked here nothing happened previously it will navigate some folder location.

I'm not sure what i changed but it worked yesterday 
Is this a temporary location error or any setting changed?

Any other alternative way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your user don't have rights to write to folder you want to export.
In Windows open the folder properties, then go to "Security" tab click "Edit" button and add your user then click "Full control" checkbox and click ok.